# How much is $\sum_{n\neq 0, n\in Z^d} \frac{\cos(n\cdot x)}{|n|^s}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

When $s\in (0,d)$ and $x\in [-\pi, \pi]^d$, how much is this sum : 
$$\sum_{\large n\neq 0, n\in Z^d} \frac{\cos(n\cdot x)}{|n|\large^s}$$
If it does not converge, can I define it in some sort of "weak sense"?

Comment: Is there an answer for $d=1$?

Comment: Which set is $Z^d$?

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: it is the set of $d$ dimensional vector with each component to be integer

Comment: for d = 1, yes, there is a answer. Z^d is the subspace of R^d with all components to be integers.